# add TOC to PDF that has both portrait and landscape pages

Tags: aspose.pdf

http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/pdfnet/Add+TOC+to+Existing+PDF

I am trying to add a TOC to a PDF that has both portrait and landscape pages similar to the example above. That causes all the pages in the PDF to become portrait and the landscape pages are cut off. Any idea what is causing that or how to fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved in the new version of aspose.pdf.